# Limited coordinate values for geo application

Tags: c#, sql-server, geometry

First, I don't know well about the `geometry` and `geography` data type usage of `sql server` but I now have to read in random data (from a file) of coordinates for each of the available functions used in these 2 CLR types (i.e `POINT`, `LINESTRING`, `POLYGON`, `CIRCULARSTRING` etc).

I need to eliminate nonsensical values e.g those of impractical use but I don't know how they becomes nonsensical data.

For example, a geographical datum out of (-180 deg, 180 deg) range.

But how about data for i.e POINT and others in geometry sense ?

Does sql server accept a big integer as one of its `x` coordinate parts of `POINT`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL Server's STIsValid function which returns true if a geometry instance is well-formed, based on its Open Geospatial Consortium (OGC) type. Returns false if a geometry instance is not well-formed.

```
DECLARE @g geometry;  
SET @g = geometry::STGeomFromText('LINESTRING(0 0, 2 2, 1 0)', 0);  
SELECT @g.STIsValid();
```

[STIsValid Full Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/stisvalid-geometry-data-type?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 0):

> Does sql server accept a big integer as one of its x coordinate parts of POINT?

No, the Lat, Long parameters are float. You can supply bigint inputs, but it doesn't make sense to:

1. they will be converted to float.
2. supplying bigint inputs means that you will be limited to whole number degrees and cannot get fractional degrees.

Compare this snippet (the decimal parts get truncated):

```sql
declare @Lat bigint = 47.65100;
declare @Long bigint = -122.34900;
declare @geo geography = geography::Point(@Lat, @Long, 4326)
select @Lat, @Long, @Geo.ToString();
```

```
-------------------- -------------------- ---------------
47                   -122                 POINT (-122 47)
```

With this snippet:

```sql
declare @Lat float = 47.65100;
declare @Long float = -122.34900;
declare @geo geography = geography::Point(@Lat, @Long, 4326)
select @Lat, @Long, @Geo.ToString();
```

```
---------------------- ---------------------- -----------------------
47.651                 -122.349               POINT (-122.349 47.651)
```

REF: [Point (geography Data Type)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/point-geography-data-type)